# htaccess redirect for root and subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, root

I want to change the URL structure of my site, and I need to make some redirects, basically i want:

www.root.com/folder/second_folder/file.php
to redirect to folder.root.com/second_folder/file.php

Is there anyway that I could force to redirect the first url, to the subdomain url? 
I also have some specific root URL's that I want to redirect to specific folders in the subdomain.

I tried various ways and nothing works so far, but only by placing my htaccess file in the root folder. If I place it in my subdomain folder, then it breaks all together.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?root\.com$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?\.php)$ http://$1.root.com/$2 [L,R=301,NE]
```